# How to change URL address in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a business requirement, where i should show a different URL in the address bar from the actual. Say for ex: I have hosted my site at Hum.com. But for some users, this URL should show up as CP.com at the address bar? Is it even possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. What if I change it to "www.myonlinebank.com"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is if you control both domains, `hum.com` and `cp.com` and if you configure your web server to serve the same application for `cp.com` and `hum.com`.

If above is the case (you control both domains), you can simply redirect the users to the appropriate domain using `Response.Redirect`.

This is easily done in Apache via `NameVirtualHosts` and I am sure IIS offers the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but it's generally done at the DNS level and not within the application itself. You want the IP address of Hum.com to resolve to the same IP address as CP.com. This is how hosting sites such as Google Sites generally work.

To do this you need to own the DNS entry for your vanity domain name (i.e. CP.com) and you need to ensure that the hosting site is capable of associating requests for CP.com with the hosted website.

Comment: But you'd still have to redirect them to the new URL. (I get the impression he doesn't control the website at the new URL.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by redirect.

```
if(fUserOfCP && !HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Contains("cp.com/")){
 Responce.Redirect(
    HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Replace("hum.com/", "cp.com/")
 , true);
}
```

This code is the idea, probably is better to break the RawUrl, check and reconstruct it on the redirect to avoid the existing of host on file name.
Assume that both names belong to you, and you have setup correctly the dns.

Rewrite is not possible on host name if this is your first thoughts.